# How to locate the php.ini file (xampp)

Tags: php, xampp, ini

I am using `xampp`server for `PHP` development and want to edit the `php.ini` file; where can I locate it?

Answer (score 123):

For **Windows**, you can find the file in the `C:\xampp\php\php.ini`-Folder (Windows) or in the `etc`-Folder (*within* the xampp-Folder).

Under **Linux**, most distributions put lampp under `/opt/lampp`, so the file can be found under `/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini`.

It can be edited using a normal Text-Editor.

**Clarification**:

- `Xampp` (**X** (for "some OS"), **A**pache, **M**ySQL, **P**erl, **P**HP)
- `Lampp` (**L**inux, **A**pache, **M**ySQL, **P**erl, **P**HP)

in this context, they can be substituted for one another.

Comment: Only with xampp on windows it is the \xampp\php folder

Comment: /etc/ deosn't have a xampp folder

Comment: /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini

Comment: @JonathanLeaders yeah, that's under4 Linux. I meant the `etc`-folder *within* the xampp/lampp folder.

Answer (score 42):

Write the following inside `phpini_path.php`( or `AnyNameAsYouLike.php`) and run it in the browser.

```
<?php phpinfo();?>
```

Among various other parameters you'll get `Loaded Configuration File` parameter which value is the path of `php.ini` on the server.

The location of `php.ini` depends on server operating system:

**Windows (With Xampp Installation)**:

```
/xampp/php/php.ini
```

**macOS, OS X:**

```
/private/etc/php.ini
```

**Linux:**

```
/etc/php.ini
/usr/bin/php5/bin/php.ini
/etc/php/php.ini
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

Comment: Incorrect. On Mac, /private/etc/php.ini doesn't exist.

Answer (score 38):

In MacOS : `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini`

Answer (score 15):

If you have multiple php-versions (xampp etc) running, I find the easiest is to use:

```
php --ini
```

from the command line. In windows: either after you click `Shell` in xampp, or directly in the regular `cmd` to find the "global" version of php. With global I mean the version referenced to by your environment variables.

Answer (score 10):

Run Xampp server.

1. Go to http://localhost which will open up xampp dashboard.
2. Go to PHPInfo link in the top navigation bar.

--- or directly type following url in the browser after run the XAMPP
http://localhost/dashboard/phpinfo.php

This will open up php info page. There you can find "Loaded Configuration File  /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini" which is the php.ini location.

Answer (score 8):

my OS is ubuntu, XAMPP installed in `/opt/lampp`, and I found php.ini in `/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini`

Comment: Thanks I have also installed xampp and found the php.ini in the above path that you mentioned :)

Answer (score 6):

Put a script somewhere in your document root

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Among others the output of the function will tell you which `php.ini`s are parsed before the script got executed.

Answer (score 2):

I've always found the easiest way is `php -i` and filtering down.

*nix (including MacOS):

```
php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"
```

Windows:

```
php -i | findstr /C:"Loaded Configuration File"
```

Of course this assumes your CLI environment is using the same PHP binaries as your actual web server.

You can always check that to be sure using `which php` in *nix and `where php` in Windows.

Comment: so, what do I do if in OSX there's no php.ini ? php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"                                                                                                                                   ✔  at 06:32:21 PM 
Loaded Configuration File => (none)

Comment: @MonaJalal: Then you do not have an ini file.  Solution (in my case): `sudo cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini`

Comment: @MonaJalal `sudo find / -type f -name "php.ini"` should help you (this will search the whole drive which could be slow, a more localized search would be faster like `find /etc -type f -name "php.ini"` for instance)

Answer (score 2):

I’ve run into the need while running on PhpStorm on my Mac. Follow the orange text.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those "you were technically accurate, but you didn't answer my question" but it doesn't mean the above were wrong or misguided - they just didn't run into my issue.

So, I figure I'll give an answer.

As the others mentioned (spot on), I created a file:

```
<?php
phpinfo(); 
?>
```

So that worked great. However, it showed "(none)"

So where do you find (none)!?

In my case, on Windows, you just go to where php is installed; I had already had installed it in `c:\php` I believe it would be the same steps on other platforms.

Then, from a command line, powershell for ex, type:  `notepad c:\php\php.ini`

Tell it yes, you do want to create it, then add whatever changes you needed in the first place. For me, for example:

```
extension_dir = "c:\php\ext"
extension=mysqli
upload_max_filesize = 25M
post_max_size = 13M
max_execution_time = 300
```

Then save. Fixed!

By the way - if you do "file new" and then "save as" Notepad will helpfully rename your file to php.ini.txt.  Friends let friends NOT AVOID THE CLI.

Comment: This feels like an entirely different question and answer posted as an answer to a nine year old question. If you remove it here, but separate it into a question and an answer you can post the question and self answer it and increase both the quality of the site and your chances of getting an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

If you have been using different installers, you may well end up with more that one php.ini file on your hdd, which could affect your sanity after a while.

Search your hdd for 'php.ini' just in case there is more than one.

Another sanity-saving move is to remember to always restart your server (apache) after altering a value in php.ini.

Answer (score 1):

i'm using xampp with PHP 7. you can trying looking for php.ini in

> /etc/php/7.0/apache2

Answer (score 1):

in my case it is present as "php.ini-development" and "php.ini-production" in php folder

Answer (score 1):

Am running `LAMP` on **Debian** and mine is in:

```
/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
```

Answer (score 1):

step1 :open xampp control panel

step 2: then click apache module  config button.

step 3. after that you able to see some config file list.

step 4: then click the php.ini file.it will be open into default editor.

image was given blow for refernce.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

php.ini Location is here in MAC BOOK XAMPP =
PHP configuration file: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html (Configuration files section, near the bottom of the page): \xampp\php\php.ini

Answer (score 0):

as KingCrunch pointed out, using phpinfo you can see what config file is in action in the "Loaded Configuration File" row. in my case in was in C:\xampp\apache\bin note that there is a php.ini also in C:\xampp\php which seems to be redundant and irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Goto xammp

Step 2: Find php Foleder and click on it,

Find 2: Below php.ini file

Path : C:\xampp\php
[image]

Second Example :
step 1: Open xampp control panel

Step 2: Click On config,

Step 3: Find Here php.ini file

[image]

To get loaded php.ini files location try:
command :   php --ini

[image]