# how do i install or enable openssl in xampp?

Tags: php, windows, apache, xampp

i have spent too many hours on google and searched how to install or enable openssl in xampp but i can't get proper solution i install or enable need openssl in xampp because of i want to install `PhreedomR35RC3 Open Source`

PhreedomR35RC3 Showing Error While Installing It!

```
The following installation errors have been found.
Errors (in red) must be fixed before the installation 
script can proceed.Cautions (in yellow) will not prevent 
installation.But may prevent modules from operating properly.
Your server needs to have openssl installed.
```

Comment: Are you sure that the extension is included/uncommented? "[PHP_OPENSSL]
extension=php_openssl.dll"

Comment: @mido wait let me check it can you tell me on which line it will be show?

Comment: Check here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185319/how-do-i-edit-php-ini-file-in-xampp-server

Answer (score 3):

Open your php.ini file, and remove the semi-colon before php_openssl.dll, then restart your server.

Answer (score 1):

1) In your php.ini file , remove comment before extension=php_openssl.dll
2) In your php configuration file , remove comment before extension=php_openssl.dll
3) restart your apache server
4) check whether openssl is enabled or not under PHAR section in Xampp homepage