# How can I upload a bigger image in PHP?

Tags: php

This is my code and I need more size for image files because I can upload up to 1M

```
// Place image in the folder
$newname = "$pid.jpg";
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "../inventory_images/$newname");
header("location: inventory_list.php");
exit();
```

Comment: So what's the problem you're having?

Comment: I think that it's not PHP dependent, is it? PHP should really not yell to you about the size of the image.

Comment: php.ini sets the max image upload size as well as the max post size

Comment: @AkshatTripathi It could be PHP or the server or something else inbetween.  The OP needs to search for the technologies being used to extend the max file upload size.

Comment: you need to edit the php.ini file and change `upload_max_filesize`

Comment: i want to upload an image but php has limit for the size of image file!so i want to increase that..

Comment: The presumption of PHP-only may be a bad lead and non-solution.  The OP could be using a browser-side service or Apache or ... with additional limitations.

Comment: Can we delete 0x21?!  Why does every noob think it's needed? /end_rant

Comment: how can include php.ini in my code?

Comment: @JakeGould Could be, but when they ask how they can include php.ini in their code... are we sure? Just sayin'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit the `php.ini` file on your server like so; making it 2M to cover for overhead:

```
upload_max_filesize = 2M
post_max_size = 2M
```

Or you can add this to your site’s `.htaccess` file:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 2M
php_value post_max_size 2M
```

Since you say you are using XAMPP, you should [look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185319/how-do-i-edit-php-ini-file-in-xampp-server) and [this blog post](http://www.sudo-juice.com/where-is-php-ini/). If you are on Windows, look here, `C:/xampp/php/php.ini`.  Open that file, find the settings for `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`, change them and restart XAMPP. You should be good to go then.

Or just open up or create an `.htaccess` file in your web server root for XAMPP and add those two lines above with the `php_value` prefix.

Comment: OK!So i must create this file and that's it?how my php communicate with php.ini.im sorry but im new in php..

Comment: i use xampp..what's the src for php.ini?