# Symfony 2 php.ini date.timezone

Tags: php, symfony

I have a problem with the setup of Symfony 2 localy on xampp.
The installation was no problem but when I execute the check.php it says:

```
Your system is not ready to run Symfony2 projects 
 * date.timezone setting must be set
   > Set the "date.timezone" setting in php.ini* (like Europe/Paris).
```

But the date.timezone in the php.ini is already set correctly.

Comment: If you check well your xampp directory you'll find more than one php.ini. Update all of them. This may help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185319/how-do-i-edit-php-ini-file-in-xampp-server#answer-17502290

Comment: But I have only one php.ini located at etc/php.ini and this one is correct

Comment: I am pretty sure, instead of editing the `php.ini` file, you can just put `ini_set('date.timezone', 'Europe/Paris');` in your index file instead.

Comment: `phpinfo()` tells the full path of the `php.ini` that was used, have you tried this ?

Comment: or run console command "php -i | grep php.ini" it will output the path

Comment: Notice that when you run PHP from the command line, a different php.ini file might be used. So you might need to set ````date.timezone```` in for example ````/etc/php5/cli/php.ini````. Also you might need to restart the Apache service after changing your Apache php.ini.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can add this to your AppKernel.php

```
public function init()
{
    // get rid of Warning: date_default_timezone_get(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone
    date_default_timezone_set( 'Europe/Paris' );
    parent::init();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! php_info() returned the path that was already the correct ini. And there was no other ini. Symfony was running despite the error. But I added the timezone to AppKernel.php and the error dispappeard

Answer (score 2):

for some reason you have to change the `date.timezone` in

> php.ini

in the

> cli folder

got the hint when I tried to start a new project in Symfony3.

even if phpinfo() shows that the

> php.ini file is in apache2 folder

Comment: Worked for me as well (Ubuntu 17.04, php 7.x).

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing following problem :

```
Your system is not ready to run Symfony2 projects 
 * date.timezone setting must be set
> Set the "date.timezone" setting in php.ini* (like Europe/Paris)
```

Simply replace the |localizeddate('long','long') with |date('r') in app/Resources/views/base.html.twig file.

Answer (score -2):

What worked for me is to add the -k option when restarting Apache