# How To regenerate Session id?

Tags: php

I am trying to regenerate session id but not getting succeed, i used session_regenerate_id(). but while we submitting form it's showing :---
"Warning: session_regenerate_id(): Cannot regenerate session id - headers already sent in C:\xampp\htdocs\yogesh_traders\yadmin\quo_pro_temp.php on line 4"

please suggest how to solve this problem

```
<?php
$old_sessionid = session_id();
session_regenerate_id();
$new_sessionid = session_id();
echo "Old Session: $old_sessionid<br />";
echo "New Session: $new_sessionid<br />";
exit();
?>
<div align="center">
<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />
</div>
<?php
/* if($_REQUEST['clear']=='y' ){
$db->Delete('quotation_pro_temp',"session_id='".session_id()."'",1);
//session_regenerate_id();
} */

if(isset($_POST['senditem']))
{
if(count($_POST['senditem'])>0)
{

foreach($_POST['senditem'] as $setitem)
{
$a=$db->SelectSingle("product_details","id='".$setitem."'","");
$data["prod_id"] =$a["id"] ;
$data["pname"] = $a['pname'];
$data["brand"] = $a['brand'];
$data["qty"] = $_POST['qty'."-".$setitem];
$data["measure"] = $a['measure'];
$data["price"] =$_POST['price'."-".$setitem];
$data["mrp_field"] =$a['mrp_field'];
$data["discount"] = $_POST['disc'."-".$setitem]."-".$_POST['distype'."-".$setitem];
$data["total"] = $_POST['equals'."-".$setitem];
$data["session_id"] =$old_sessionid;
$db->Insert('quotation_pro_temp',$data);
echo "<meta HTTP-EQUIV=\"REFRESH\" content=\"0; url=inner_index.php?pagename=quotation_productwise_view&ins=y\">";  
}
}
}   
?>
```

Comment: Use `ob_*` functions to capture output instead of direct printing it.

Comment: *headers already sent* take sure, that you don't have any output before you call session_regenerate_id()

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: @Randyka Yudhistria : Please check above code

Comment: for stop execution it's used at this time i am only checking new and old id same or different that's why i used this exit() function .

Comment: I give 99% that you include this file somewhere else and you outputted something before include.

Comment: @Forien : in header file only i used session_start() ; nothing else included.

Comment: Even if you have an `space`, `enter`, `tab` or anything outside `<?php` and `?>` is output.

Comment: @Mahesh it works perfectly for me (copied your code and added `session_start()` between line 1 and 2. **YOU DID** some output. It can be anything, an `echo`, empty space between `?> .. <?php` or whitespace before `<?php`. Code you provided is perfectly fine, problem lies in other files that comes before this file is included

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call this function before anything is send to the client (before any output).

Make sure you don't have anything that outputs before this code (non php code or `echo`'s for example) or move the function up.

You can also use output buffering (see [ob_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)) to send all the output to a buffer instead of sending it directly to the client.

Is also possible to turn on output buffering by default, set  [output-buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering) in php.ini to 'On' and restart your server. See also this: [How do i edit php.ini file in xampp server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185319/how-do-i-edit-php-ini-file-in-xampp-server)

After your edit:
Make sure `<?php` is on the first line and there is no white space before it. Your error says line 4, but the code is on line 3.

Comment: i did this but its not working please check above code

Comment: yes after regenerate id at the time of $new_sessionid it's showing that error but why i am not getting

Answer (score 0):

1. You forgot to call session_start().
2. Make sure you don't have any output before "session_start()", or you'll get "headers already sent error".
3. I tried your code in a separate php file and everything works fine:

```
<?php  
session_start();  

$old_sessionid = session_id();  
session_regenerate_id();  
$new_sessionid = session_id();  

echo "Old Session: $old_sessionid";  
echo "New Session: $new_sessionid";  
exit;  
?>
```