# Menu not adding anything

Tags: sql, wordpress, menu

Currently im finishing a project in school in which i have to use wp-commerce to make a shopping site, and for some reason today i cannot add anything to a menu. It says "menu has been updated, but nothing is added, so i add a menu menu ad then everything is greyed out if i try to add anything. I have tried the other solutions to the "cannot insert menu into database" such as switch themes and even reinstalling wordpress. I look in the sql and inside wp terms, the new menu i put up is added with a term id of 0.
[Here is a screenshot of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgyYz.png)

Help would be appreciated, i really do not want to start this all over again, so of there is a solution to fix this, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check you php.init file this `Max_input_vars` and you need to update in php.ini file the below value.

Max_input_vars =9000

Try this.

Comment: How do i get to the php.ini file? Im new to this

Comment: Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185319/how-to-locate-the-php-ini-file-xampp