# How to fix HTTP error on WordPress when uploading an image?

Tags: php, wordpress, http, xampp

I read all the suggestions online but none of them working for me .The problem I'm having is when I'm trying to upload an image on WordPress it gives HTTP error. I did change the ('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '2000M'); but still did not work. I am running with xampp.

Comment: Check the `memory_limit` option in your php.ini

Comment: tnx @IvnH how much it should be?

Comment: Can you give me some more hand plz

Comment: Set like this: memory_limit = 256M;

Comment: i can not find php.ini on my folder where can i find it bro

Comment: [How to locate the php.ini file (xampp)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185319/how-to-locate-the-php-ini-file-xampp)

Comment: I found the file but there is no memory_limit ,should i add that?

Comment: add the memory_limit and restart your web server after you've done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change it globaly in `php.ini` (in xampp located in '`\xampp\php\php.ini`'):

```
memory_limit = 256M // search for this "memory_limit" and adjust it by your needs.
```

if there is no memory_limit in your php.ini file add it and restart xampp/web server