# data is inserting in db but displaying error

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I'm working on user login_register from, when I signup then data inserts into DB (and can also login), but the browser says:

```
   maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded
```

in \vendor\phpunit\phpunit\appveyor.yml: its already 1200

```
  - IF NOT EXIST php-installed.txt echo max_execution_time=1200 >> php.ini
```

when I signup then data is submitted into DB but it shows this https://ibb.co/YLv6N5g
any solution to resolve this issue

Comment: rather than monkeying with config can you chunk your query? How many queries are you running?

Comment: 12 queries.....

Comment: Thats doesnt sound too much of a query.  Would you mind sharing you eloquent query so that I can have a look.

Answer (score 5):

Update `max_execution_time` in your **php.ini** file

```
; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
; http://php.net/max-execution-time
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to 0 for the CLI SAPI
max_execution_time = 300
```

This will set the execution time to 5 minutes.

**Note:** do not forget to restart apache server.

For Windows, you can find the file in the C:\xampp\php\php.ini-Folder (Windows) or in the etc-Folder (within the xampp-Folder).

Here is question for detail about this.
[How to locate the php.ini file (xampp)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185319/how-to-locate-the-php-ini-file-xampp)

Comment: can u plz tell me where is this file located

Comment: @programmer0001 What's your system windows or linux ?

Comment: @programmer0001 **xampp/php/php.ini** (for Windows User)

Comment: @programmer0001 did you restart xampp ?

Comment: yes restart it, clear the browser history but still same issue

Comment: @programmer0001 I think it should work, did you make changes to correct file ?

Comment: i hv make changes in both php.ini-development and php.ini-production file

Comment: @programmer0001 this may happen if csrf token failure occurred. what is your opinion Sagar

Comment: @YachithaSandaruwan May be csrf token is missing there

Comment: @programmer0001 Check your signup form and login form both have declared csrf token.

Comment: @YachithaSandaruwan both hv csrf token

Comment: @programmer0001 can you add your error in above post

Comment: @programmer0001 May be due to caching issue. Please clear the configuration cache in laravel application with `php artisan config:cache` command in console

Comment: I think it's better to upload your blade or whatever fronted forms and back-end configuration since the error cannot be specifically identified. Still by changing the maximum execution time, not direct you to any solution.

Comment: @YachithaSandaruwan    all links are here in a reply https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/data-is-inserting-in-db-but-displaying-error

Comment: I have gone through your code and there aren't any errors in it. So as @SagarGautam said try by clear and reconfigure cache by using `php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 1):

you will need to change is `max_execution_time`

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Resource Limits ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

max_execution_time = 30     ; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
max_input_time = 60 ; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data
memory_limit = 8M      ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (8MB)
```

You can change the max_execution_time to 300 seconds like `max_execution_time = 300`

You can find the path of your PHP configuration file in your **xampp/php/php.ini**(Windows User) file And don't forget to restart your server

Comment: still same issue after it

Answer (score 1):

A php execution process if its connecting DB and doing insert or just simple loop, php will make sure it is always executed under a time limit which is set in php.ini's configuration called 'max_execution_time'. This avoids unnecessary resources used by a php script when it runs for extremely long time.

Now server may have multiple `php.ini`'s, sometimes one for `cli` and one which actually affects the web server. You can do

```
<?php 
phpinfo();
exit;
```

at the start of `public/index.php` once or create a `public/test.php` file and add that in it(delete it once you see the data). In that you will be able to see correct location of `php.ini`

Also, the same phpinfo page will help you see the `max_execution_time` as well. So if you have increased it correctly, it should show the updated value  there.

Going one step further, increasing the value even if resolves your issue, you should spend some time why it is taking so much time. For a normal request without large file posted to server, 30-60 seconds is a pretty decent execution time limit.

Comment: its showing into 2 places i hv edited it in D:\xampp but m unable to find it in C:\windows  https://ibb.co/p1Kv0PC

Comment: see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185319/how-to-locate-the-php-ini-file-xampp) helps