# What does xampp expect as a php.ini?

Tags: php, xampp

I am using xampp and in the process of trying to debug with netbeans I am getting "Waiting For Connection". In searching the web I found that the php.ini needs to be edited but I am not sure which one. When I go into the PHP folder through xampp there is php.ini-production and php.ini-development. I read the comments in the file but I still do not understand. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

I have searched around stack overflow and found the proper code for the ini but it seems there is nothing that shows you how to set the ini up in xampp.

I want to fix the php.ini file so that I can debug with netbeans

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to locate the php.ini file (xampp)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185319/how-to-locate-the-php-ini-file-xampp)

Answer (score 1):

Well to find out the location of your php.ini file, you can create a file called phpinfo.php with the following function: **phpinfo()**.

This will display information about your Php installation including the path to the php.ini file.

Also see this related question: [How to locate the php.ini file (xampp)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185319/how-to-locate-the-php-ini-file-xampp/44826055)

Comment: Found it but debug is still not working. I installed xdebug and set the path in the php.ini still nothing and the php info says that it is not in there

Comment: What is the exact error that you are getting ?. Also see this link: http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug

Comment: When I go to the php info file there is no mention of the xdebug extension, the article you sent tells me that zend is no longer compatible with it. I followed the instructions in the PHP/Mysql Murach book but its from 2017 so who knows how much that is reliable. The NetBeans IDE is just saying waiting for connection and doesn't give an errors.

Comment: I am getting from the book that I need to add the lines (zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.7.2-7.3-vc15-nts-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=1) to the php.ini.

Comment: I guess my question is misleading. I started with being confused about the ini since I am used to servers not a windows local machine when it comes to actually seeing the ini and not configuation setting in the directory

Comment: You should check the Xampp error log files. They should contain more information about the error

Comment: Failed loading C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.7.2-7.3-vc15-nts-x86_64.dll
www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Comment: Well you have mentioned two errors. The first error says that Xampp was not able to load the XDebug extension. A search on Google for this error showed the following page: https://gist.github.com/odan/1abe76d373a9cbb15bed. Two solutions are mentioned. The first solution is to make sure you are loading the correct XDebug binary file version. If you run the XDebug wizard, it will tell you which version of XDebug to use with your Php version. The second solution is to right click on the php_xdebug-2.7.2-7.3-vc15-nts-x86_64.dll file and click on unblock

Comment: The second error you mentioned says that the SSL certificate for www.example could not be loaded. Maybe you have configured www.example.com as your host name in Xampp or you are trying to access a locally hosted website using www.example.com

Comment: It is a lost cause, teacher said that it was bull. Thank you for trying though. I think that the reason that it is not working is because of the zend is uncompatible. Thank you :)